# How to use Linq To XML to get multiple elements and store them differently?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<MainData id="1" >
<Info>
<Date>2015-06-08 15:00:00</Date>
</Info>
<Data DataRef="uu91"/>
<Data DataRef="uu92">
</Data>
</MainData>
```

I have an xml file and I want to take the two data element and store them into two different variable so when I do the same value comes out. when I receive these two values I would like to get the ID, Date...

```
var data = from item in retreiveOptaHomeFixturesXml.Descendants("MainData")
                   select new
                   {
                       ID = item.Attribute("id").Value,
                       Date = item.Element("Info").Element("Date").Value,
                       DataRef1 = item.Element("Data").Attribute("DataRef").Value,
                       Dataref2 = item.Element("Data").Attribute("DataRef").Value,
                   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should be fetching the `DataRef` into a list because in each `MainData` you will have multiple data with `DataRef` attribute. You can do it like this:-

```
 var data = from item in x1.Descendants("MainData")
            let dataNodes = item.Elements("Data")
            select new
                  {
                     ID = item.Attribute("id").Value,
                     Date = item.Element("Info").Element("Date").Value,
                     DataRef1Ref2 = dataNodes.Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("DataRef"))
                                             .ToList()
                  };
```